# Dynamic fields with Go html template

Tags: go, go-templates, go-html-template

Can I make a html template in go work with dynamic properties?

Like this for example currently results in the error

> Invalid template: template: sticker.CellRepresentation:1:23: executing "sticker.CellRepresentation" at <.sticker_set.url>: can't evaluate field url in type interface {}

```golang
func sample() error {
    tpl, err := template.New("sample").Parse(`<a href="${sticker_set.url}">{{.sticker_set.url}}</a>`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "sticker_set": map[string]interface{}{
            "url": "x",
        },
    }

    if err := tpl.Execute(NoopWriter{}, data); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid template: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := sample()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I'm not using structs because the template I'm trying to execute works with a json of a structure that's not defined at compile time

Comment: The code in the question does not produce the error cited: https://play.golang.org/p/xWbjObZCF9h. Please share the actual code that you have problems with.

Comment: @mkopriva oh, true, my mistake. The code I've posted is a trivialized version but it's the one I've actually executed, that is except that I've kept the original code after it in main and wanted to insert a `return` before it to quickly analyze what the problem is. Didn't notice that this code actually worked and the original code that came after caused the cause because the template was the same

Comment: If you're still having issues resolving the problem feel free to update the question with a code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: I did a quick search and that error can be shown if you try to access something that is `nil`.

Comment: @TehSphinX something similiar to that actually turned out to be the issue, although in my case it wasn't `nil` but an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me and on the playground. I adjusted the template a bit and used `os.stdout` as writer.

```golang
func sample() error {
    tpl, err := template.New("sample").Parse(`<a href="{{.sticker_set.url}}">{{.sticker_set.url}}</a>`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "sticker_set": map[string]interface{}{
            "url": "xyz",
        },
    }

    if err := tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid template: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Even tried it with different value types: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lA_Qh2SzSRn)